# Numerical Integration (Midpoint Rule)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Hello dears I will appreciate if any one helps with solutions with steps :)

> Midpoint rule is used to solve this integration:
>   $$
> \int_0^{x_n} x^3\, dx
> $$
>   and equal to $35$. Find $x_n$ is represented end point of integration using a numerical technique and $n=3$?

Comment: Please type out your image as not all users can see images, and they are not searchable so less people will see your question. Use [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type out the Maths nicely. Also, you need to add some of your working - we are not here to blindly answer your homework questions.

Comment: You add up $((k+\frac12)h)^3h$ until you hit $35$ and then do some linear interpolation? Or treat the 3-segment formula as a function of $x_n$ and apply the bisection, false position, secant method or any other method of your choice.

Comment: Use your favorite root-finding method (e.g. Newton, bisection, secant, fixed point iteration etc..) in combination with the midpoint rule.

Comment: @projectilemotion Thanks

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann thanks

Comment: @lioness99a appreciation but I found it difficult why not to use a simple menu instead of these difficult programming symbols.

Comment: @Matho-Patho It's a pretty standard way to write Maths formula. It's pretty easy once you get used to it

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Q now without using any of your root finding methods only algebraically and of-course with Midpoint Rule. See the attached image please. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZuFq.jpg)
**If any of you have another method please share it with us not only by saying but by steps please.**